# How to read all images in folder?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to execute this code to read a set of images present in a folder with python language but I have a problem if you can help me

```
patient_uids = train_annotations.seriesuid.unique()

patients_processed_files = glob.glob(OUTPUT_FOLDER + '[0-9\.]*_X.npy')
patients_processed = set()
for filename in patients_processed_files:
    m = re.match(r'([0-9\.]*)_X.npy', os.path.basename(filename))
    patients_processed.add(m.group(1))

print(len(patient_uids))

graph = tf.Graph()
with graph.as_default():
    img_chunk = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[CHUNK_SIZE, CHUNK_SIZE, CHUNK_SIZE], name='img_chunk')
    img_flipped_up_down = tf.image.flip_up_down(img_chunk)
    img_flipped_left_right = tf.image.flip_left_right(img_chunk)
    img_rot_90 = tf.image.rot90(img_chunk)
    img_trans = tf.image.transpose_image(img_chunk)

weird_chunks = {}

for patient_uid in patient_uids:
    if patient_uid in patients_processed:
        print('Skipping already processed patient {}'.format(patient_uid))
        continue
    print('Processing patient {}'.format(patient_uid))

    patient_annotations = train_annotations[train_annotations.seriesuid == patient_uid]
    patient_scans_path = glob.glob(DATA_PATH + 'subset?/{}.mhd'.format(patient_uid))[0]
    img, origin, spacing = load_itk(patient_scans_path)
```

but the execution of my code returns me:

`IndexError: list index out of range`

Comment: Hi there, please include the full traceback of the error you're getting. It'll help you and us pinpoint and fix the error quicker. Thanks. :-)

Comment: Welcome @maram to SO. Please read on how to write a good question. TLDR; we need the traceback you have, your assumptions on what could have caused that issue and any elements you think will help in reproducing and resolving the issue. And don't forget to put docstrings in your code to explain what you are doing and why you are doing it.

Answer (score 0):

Only place where I see you are using indexing directly is line

```
patient_scans_path = glob.glob(DATA_PATH + 'subset?/{}.mhd'.format(patient_uid))[0]
```

so this is most probably causing your error. It looks like there is not any path matching your pattern. Please add directly before that line

```
print(len(glob.glob(DATA_PATH + 'subset?/{}.mhd'.format(patient_uid))))
```

to check how many elements were matched, if it is equal `0` problem is there.

Comment: yes the result of print is 0 and indeed the error comes from this line